# How to protect Downloader folder?

Tags: downloader

In many Magento store using /downloader you will get access to a from to access backend. Do for your own a test, once you find a Magento store, change the url pointing to /downloader. Even you changed admin in local.xml to any name you wanted for admin url, you have this backdoor to your administration page through Downloader. Main question, how do I protect this folder being access only from backend menu by admin?

First thoughts:

1) I can password protect this folder. Will it be accessible from backend using Magento Connect link?

2) Can I change inside Magento files the name for Downloader folder? The idea is changing in prompt Downloader folder name to other name hard to find (eg downloader21). Are they many files to change? Having the menu working in backend for System->Magento Connect

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't the basic [.htaccess](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/downloader/.htaccess) work for you?

Comment: Just use .htaccess to 403 that particular directory for all but the IP addresses you use for admin access.

Comment: I am not using Apache anymore. Nginx is the way for Magento. Because I am the sysadmin, I will rename the whole directory, then when I need the Downloader I will put it back for a few minutes. There is another way to protect it same like in Apache, Nginx has the same feature. As an advice Nginx plus HHVM are just fantastic for Magento. I really boosted my performance with 100% just switching from Apache + PHP 5.5 to Nginx + HHVM.

Comment: _I am not using Apache anymore._ nginx allows for access rule sets, if you intend on this site to be secure, you will need to reflect all those stock `.htaccess` rules created by a Magento install into your nginx installation. In addition, you can still protect the downloader access to serve a 403 for unwanted inbound traffic.